Samba not starting dependency error (CentOS)
smbd refuses to start.
Giving the command  smbd,
I get this.
smbd: /usr/lib64/samba/libreplace-samba4.so: version `SAMBA_4.10.16' not found (required by /lib64/libwbclient.so.0)
smbd: /usr/lib64/samba/libwinbind-client-samba4.so: version `SAMBA_4.10.16' not found (required by /lib64/libwbclient.so.0)

yum provides libreplace-samba4.so
samba-client-libs-4.7.1-6.el7.i686 : Samba client libraries
Repo        : C7.5.1804-base
Matched from:
Provides    : libreplace-samba4.so

Note: this is a .i686 file. My CentOS version is x86_64
Trying to erase these files
yum erase samba-client-libs-4.7.1-6.el7.i686
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
No Match for argument: samba-client-libs-4.7.1-6.el7.i686
No Packages marked for removal

How do I fix this?

There's currently no supported CentOS release available. You should upgrade to a supported OS.

The error is due to a mismatch in the versions of the samba libraries installed on your system. Specifically, it seems there is an issue with the libwbclient.so.0 library requiring a different version of libreplace-samba4.so and libwinbind-client-samba4.so.
Check current samba packages:
rpm -qa | grep samba

If you find any 32-bit (i686) Samba packages installed, you should remove them:
yum remove samba-client-libs-4.7.1-6.el7.i686

Then clean the YUM cache:
yum clean all

Now, install the correct version of samba:
yum install samba samba-client samba-client-libs

After installing the correct packages, verify the installation:
smbd --version

Finally, try restarting the samba service:
systemctl restart smb
systemctl restart nmb
systemctl restart winbind

If there are still issues, check the status and logs for more detailed error messages:
systemctl status smb
journalctl -xe

Good luck!
